# Subsequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

"Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence. Let $\{b_{n_k}\}$ and $\{c_{n_k}\}$ be subsequences of $\{a_n\}$.  Prove directly that if $b_{n_k} \to b$ and $c_{n_k} \to c$ with $b \neq c$, then $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $c$. (Note: $b$ and $c$ are interchangeable)"

I've been stuck on this homework question for a really long time. 
I can't use the fact that all subsequences of a sequence converge to the same limit as part of my proof so I'm really stuck =/

hints on how to start? :3

Comment: well, go for contradiction and use the definition of convergence

Comment: Yes i thought about contradiction but the directions say to prove directly. I'm really confused as to how to approach it directly

Comment: ah sorry about that; my reading abilities are lacking. Okay - think about what it means for $a_n$ to not converge to $c.$ This means that there exists $\epsilon$ and an (increasing) sequence $N_k$ such that $|a_{N_k} - c| \ge \epsilon.$ How would you draw this conclusion from what you're given?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ 0 < \epsilon < \frac{|b-c|}{2}$, and let $N$ be large enough so that $k \geq N$ implies $|b_k - b| < \epsilon$. Then for all $k \geq N$, $|a_{n_k} - b| < \epsilon$. By the reverse triangle inequality,
$$|a_{n_k} - c| = |(a_{n_k} - b) + (b-c)| \geq ||a_{n_k} - b| - |b-c|| > \frac{|b-c|}{2},$$
which means that $\{a_n\}$ cannot converge to $c$.

Comment: I tried a similar approach but got stuck when I didn't know what to set ϵ equal to. How did you arrive at ϵ<|b−c|/2?

Comment: Did you see my comment above? The idea is that you want $a_n$ to be close to $b$ but far from $c.$ If $|a_n - b| < \epsilon,$ then $|a_n - c| \ge |b-c| - |b-a_n|$ by the triangle inequality. So taking $\epsilon$ as anything less than $|b-c|$ will get you some sort of lower bound on $|a_n - c|.$ He chose $\epsilon < |b-c|/2$ just because it's in the middle